systemctl status systemd-networkd
Yesterday I performed an upgrade of my Ubuntu Server 20.04 to 22.04
And now there is one services that fails.
× systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-06-03 08:10:15 CEST; 6min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
    Process: 1367 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1367 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4ms

Jun 03 08:08:14 server systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Jun 03 08:10:15 server systemd-networkd-wait-online[1367]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Jun 03 08:10:15 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 08:10:15 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 03 08:10:15 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.

I tried as mentioned https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490962 to execute:
sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

and add:
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any

But that fails when I try to save the file with:
Editing "/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf" canceled: temporary file is empty.

During boot, I see the following:
Jun 03 09:03:59 server systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Jun 03 09:03:59 server systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Jun 03 09:05:59 server systemd-networkd-wait-online[1369]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Jun 03 09:05:59 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 09:05:59 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 03 09:05:59 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
Jun 03 09:05:59 server systemd[1]: Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...


For the rest, everything seems to work fine.
Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Did you read the doc file as the error tells you? Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)

No I did not. I tried to fix the config file but that failed. Before the upgrade to 22.04 it worked fine on 20.04. I did not change anything in the meanwhile.
